# Do Agama shastras say anything about how small/big temples can be?

Tags: temple, agamas

From website [qz.com](https://qz.com/408493/india-is-building-the-worlds-biggest-temple-even-bigger-than-angkor-wat/),

> Angkor Wat could potentially lose its status as the world’s largest religious monument to a $78 million upstart being conceived in the backlands of Bihar, one of India’s most impoverished provinces.
>
> The proposed temple, named Viraat Ramayan Mandir (Majestic Ramayan Temple), will be 379 feet tall with 18 spires spread across 200 acres of land. In comparison, Cambodia’s Angkor Wat—sprawling over 500 acres, equivalent to more than 300 football fields—is 215 feet tall with nine spires, but will remain the largest temple in terms of land size."

Is this consistent with Agama shastra? In other words, do Agama shastras say anything about how small/big temples can be?

Comment: Yes, Agamas allow for building large temples. If I have to simplify they give you proportions, shapes, materials, rituals that are performed not fixed sized.