# While praying, who are allowed to touch/caress "Shiva Linga", the sacred phallus?

Tags: shiva, practice, worship, culture, shiva-lingam

As per this thread, there are various opinions of whether the idol at the temple should be touched or not: [Is it allowed to hug/touch the main idol at a temple?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/24682/1049)

Now there is a special case of Shiva, which is known as "formless" (*Nirguna/NirAkAra*) aspect of Brahman, hence it may not have any idol as such. Yet, it's primarily worshiped in form of *"Linga"* (Phallus/Penis): [Why is Shiva primarily worshipped in a linga form?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/101/1049)

Many years back, our history professor told that, Not everyone should "touch" or "caress" the *Shiva Linga*. Especially women shouldn't do that, for the sake of modesty.
But in case of God, shouldn't everyone have equal rights, especially in today's era!
[image]

Who are allowed to touch/caress, the "Shiva Linga" while worshiping?

Comment: There are no restrictions of women touching Shiva Lingas or depending on Sthala Puranas, one can touch Shiva Lingas. In Kashi, you can see many women touching Shiva Lingas.  If In Kashi itself it is allowed, then it can be allowed in  any Shiva temple.

Comment: Read  question [If Shiva Linga is worshiped in all yugas then what curse did Rishi Bhrigu give to Lord Shiva?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19251/3500). Shiva Linga is not Phallus always. It a formless representation with form. **arUparUpa**

Comment: It depends on the temple rituals. It's not specific to your question, but I'll tell you an example. In Ujjain Mahakaleshwara temple, every morning there are total 56 Aarti have been done. Among them there is one Aarti called, "Bhasma Aarti", during this aarti Pundits tell every gals or woman to close their eyes or cover it with their saree. So in my opinion it all depends upon the ritual of temple.